# C++ Pointer to Pointer that points to Dynamic Array

Tags: c++, pointers

Hi I am trying to create this pointer, is this a correct way?

Pointer that I have:

```
class listaFiguras {

    //Atributos
    int numElementos;
    figuraGeom **lista = new (figuraGeom*)[0];

public :

    //Constructor sin parametros
    listaFiguras();

    //Destructor
    ~listaFiguras();

    //Sets y Gets
    void setnumElementos(int);
    virtual void setLista(figuraGeom**);

    int getnumElementos();
    virtual figuraGeom* getLista();

    //Vaciar lista
    void vaciarLista();

    //Añadir elemento
    void anyadirElemento(figuraGeom *);

};
```

This is what I have to do:

List: pointer to pointer to FIG. Points to a dynamic array, each element of which is a pointer to FIG.

Thank you in advance !

Comment: So far, so good. Do you know how to construct a dynamic array?

Comment: Yes, but not how to implement it :/

Comment: BTW, you should prefer to use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<FIG>>`.

Comment: Don't use bare pointers and prefer `std::vector` over dynamically allocated arrays (Note: "Dynamic Array" is a poor term and can denote an array that changes size dynamically. "Dynamically Allocated" is a better term).

Comment: But with std::vector I can do a pointer to pointer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to allocate everything from scratch, you could take

```
FIG ** list = new (FIG*)[number_of_pointers];
for(uint i = 0; i<number_of_pointers; ++i)
{
    //Set pointer to a new FIG object.
    list[i] = new FIG(constructor_arguments);
}
```

Comment: I edited my post with the real information that I have on the class, but I can't implement figuraGeom **lista = new (figuraGeom*)[0];

Comment: `number_of_pointers` should not be zero, it should be the size of your list.